# Open url in a new table with out domain in Shiny app

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, dt

I have created this reactive dashboard: https://lexbit.shinyapps.io/dashboard/.

I want to open the url in a new windows and download the document. You can make this manually, but when I click on the url, the url opens with the domain name of my dashboard. For example:

https://lexbit.shinyapps.io/dashboard/_w_fb3d3c12/servicio.indecopi.gob.pe/buscadorResoluciones/getDoc?docID=workspace://SpacesStore/75c8f179-e601-4928-a000-65e41446c048

An I want only "servicio.indecopi.gob.pe/buscadorResoluciones/getDoc?docID=workspace://SpacesStore/75c8f179-e601-4928-a000-65e41446c048 " (this give a pdf).

How can I solve this? This is my code:

`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

#setwd("C:/Users/Abner/Desktop/Projects/GitHub/ShinyLexBit")

##### ####
data <- read.csv('data/competencia_desleal_v2.csv', sep = ",")
data <- data[, !names(data) %in% c("Sumilla", "Partes")]  ## Saque columnas que son muy anchas
data$Enlace <- paste0("<a href='",data$Enlace,"' target='_blank'>",data$Enlace,"</a>")
#download
#### SHINY UI ###
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Resoluciones"),
  fluidRow(
    lapply(names(data)[5:length(names(data))], function(col) {  ## Exclude first four columns
      column(width = 3,
             selectInput(paste0("filter_", col), paste(col, "Filter"), choices = c("Todos", "Si", "No")))
    })
  ),
  DTOutput("table"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter label {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
    "))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data_filtered <- data
    for (col in names(data)[5:length(names(data))]) {  ## Exclude first four columns
      if (!is.null(input[[paste0("filter_", col)]])) {
        filter_value <- input[[paste0("filter_", col)]]
        if (filter_value != "Todos") {  ## Change from "All" to "Todos"
          data_filtered <- data_filtered[data_filtered[[col]] == filter_value, ]
        }
      }
    }
    return(data_filtered)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data(), selection = "none", 
              options = list(
                language = list(
                  search = "Buscar",
                  lengthMenu = "Ver _MENU_ entradas"
                )
              ),  escape = FALSE)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
```

A code to solve the problem

Comment: Do you mean the links in the "enlace" column of the table? When I click on them I get the pdf opening in a new window as you want it to.

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue. Thanks! I will close the question